# Pattern Export/Preview Quality in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, patterns

I don't know how to state this problem nor to google it. I made a pattern on Illustrator, it's a quite complicated pattern, but it's ok on my preview (left) I use my GPU Preview for working default. the right image shows the pattern in CPU Preview. I thought it's still OK, its just my CPU/GPU difference. but after I export it in JPG highest quality, and PDF highest quality, the pattern looks like the middle image. And so I printed those image, the quality of the pattern unchanged.

My goals are to make a seamless pattern, yet the glitch makes it uglier than seamed pattern :(

if anyone knows how to deal with this problem, please help me. thanks.[image: Preview images]

Comment: Hi @louislugas, welcome to GD.SE. Did you try opening the Illustrator file in Photoshop and saving the .jpg from there?

Comment: Hi @Danielillo, thank you for your reply. Yes it works! but I don't know about the PDF export quality, so i have to crank up the pixels from 3k x 6k pixels (adobe illustrator) to 12.5k x 25k pixels (adobe photoshop). I need it to print in large format, 3x6 meters. But yes it works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

My **guess** would be your pattern has a duplication on one of the sides.

The GPU is antialiasing things better (but you can still see the duplication faintly), the CPU and export are anti-aliasing things incorrectly.

I'd check the pattern to make certain one of the sides doesn't have a small part extending past the edge of the defining rectangle.

Based upon the filed area, this duplication would only show twice. If the enclosing pattern-filled rectangle were extended to show more area, you *should* see it repeat more often.

Comment: Hi @Scott, thanks before. No my pattern had no duplication, i made it clearly and merge it so no room for duplication.